# Control - C on a password prompt on the terminal

Tags: terminal

Occasionally, I request something with `sudo`, but change my mind after the password prompt has arisen. If the program was executing, I could press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit, but this has no effect on the password prompt. If it was `gksudo`, then I could likewise press <kbd>Cancel</kbd>.

So, is there anyway I could cancel *sudo*'s password prompt besides pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> multiple times, waiting for the *wrong password* dialogue?

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/582201/bash-control-c-behavior-c-gksudo-vs-sudo) might shed some light.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to find acceptable explanation for that. It does not occur with every command. For instance, if you try `sudo ls` you can usually terminate it using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

You can still press enter immediately followed by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, that usually works.

Comment: True. I can't find now what command was causing the issue with the password prompt. Did you happen to find one?

Comment: No, I was unable to find any, but I know they exist, because I have encountered same problem sometimes.